# Does java has an option to control the CPU usage when start a process

Tags: java, cpu-usage

Does java has an option to control the CPU usage while starting a process? We have a use case that there are multiple Java processes running simultaneously, and we want to limit how much CPU time each process can take at the most so that it can not affect other processes.

Comment: That is usually an OS feature.

Comment: `man ulimit` on Unix or http://serverfault.com/questions/133122/ulimit-for-windows on Windows.

Comment: Yes. Understand that. But in our use case, child java processes are created on the fly, and we are seeking a way to control the child process's usage on CPU time.

Comment: it is process. Basically we start a child JVM.

Comment: Would suggest writing an OS script that does the limiting. launch process then run the script.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM has no control over CPU usage nor priority.

Yet you can run each JVM in a separate [Docker container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).
And control the resource allocation for each container. That is exactly the added value of the Docker containers.